# RRC filter or rectangular pulse shaping filter in LFM chirp signal

Tags: digital-communications, radar

I am working with a LFM up chirp signal, and I wanted to embed some data on it using a BPSK constellation. My doubt was, ¿should I use a RRC filter, like in usual communications schemes, or should I use a rectangular pulse shaping filter? ¿Is there any advantage to use a rectangular pulse shaping filter in this case?

Comment: It's not really a lfm chirp any more if you modulate it with a data signal, so not quite sure how this whole thing works out

Comment: It's a data modulated chirp. You create a data signal, and use it to modulated the LFM chirp. So you can use the signal for radar and communication

Comment: yeah, but by modulating the chirp it *can't* be a linear frequency chirp anymore; the phase isn't any longer a quadratic function of time! You can't have a full half moon.

Comment: What do you mean by full half moon? Certainly, the frequency would change. Nonetheless there are techniques to embed data into it a chirp signal, and still have good radar performance

Comment: I meant that you can't have a "wet dry" thing, or an "even odd" number: you can't have a linear chirp that is also BPSK-modulated. It's self-contradictory. You can have something *similar*, but can not be **L**CM anymore!

Comment: I understand what you mean, but still you could use the LFM chirp as a carrier instead of a normal cosine or sine.

Comment: yeah, that's true! but the point is if you do that, you need to be defining a receiver which can initial-frequency synchronization, and phase-recovery/synchronization – which is a problem much harder than doing that with a straight cosine or sine. And: the pulse shape is often a design choice based on the synchronization and spectral mask requirements; without knowing how you're doing the sync, it's hard to advise you.